# How to re size my cards / divs using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, grid-system

I am working on  UI using bootstrap, I have some cads / divs which I am showing using using `Bootstrap-4` grid system and it is working fine.

What I am trying to is to allow user to resize those cards / widgets.

So I am using

```
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
```

and that is working fine until I got the issue.

The issue is I have given some grid like `col-lg-3` so I am not able to resize it beyond that because its total width is `col-lg-3`

SO here I am stuck don't know what to use to achieve what I am trying to.

**My code**

```
    <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
      <div class="col-11 col-sm-11 col-md-11 col-lg-11 col-xl-11 testCard d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <p>hi am a card</p>
    </div>
      </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
      <div class="col-11 col-sm-11 col-md-11 col-lg-11 col-xl-11  testCard d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <p>hi am a card2</p>
    </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

My css

```
    .testCard{
     background-color:#96bed6;
    height:100px;
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Ps- I know why it is happening, because I am fixing the width using grid-system,but I need to make my website responsive so for that I am using this.

I just want to know I can I achieve this.

My Working code

```css
.testCard {
  background-color: #96bed6;
  height: 100px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Popper JS -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
      <div class="col-11 col-sm-11 col-md-11 col-lg-11 col-xl-11 testCard d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <p>hi am a card</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
      <div class="col-11 col-sm-11 col-md-11 col-lg-11 col-xl-11  testCard d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <p>hi am a card2</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**I just want to know what would be the simplest way to achieve this, by which my Ui will be responsive and I can do resizing as well as drag n drop If I want**

Resizing an d responsive is imp for me as per now

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty weird thing to do when using a grid because you're trying to defeat the purpose of a grid.  One way to do this is to add a `max-width` to the `.testcard` And it should let it grow while still kind of keeping the grid responsive.

I've added this to `.testcard`:

`max-width: 100vw !important;`

Take a look:

```css
.testCard {
  background-color: #96bed6;
  height: 100px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  max-width: 100vw !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Popper JS -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
      <div class="col-11 col-sm-11 col-md-11 col-lg-11 col-xl-11 testCard d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <p>hi am a card</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
      <div class="col-11 col-sm-11 col-md-11 col-lg-11 col-xl-11  testCard d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <p>hi am a card2</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

but other than that, if this doesn't work for you, I'd consider using something other than a grid.

Comment: could you suggest me something else I should use, which is responsive as well as resizing also, because here the issue is when I resize the one div the other one is not displaced it is fixed it is still there. which is not default behavior of resize

Answer (score 0):

To resize or reduce Bootstrap Cards

---

In div add

```
style="width:27rem; height:27rem;"
```

```css
.testCard {
  background-color: #96bed6;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Resize Bootstrap Cars</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Popper JS -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
      <div class="col-11 col-sm-11 col-md-11 col-lg-11 col-xl-11 testCard d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" style="width:27rem; height:27rem;">
        <p>hi am a card</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
      <div class="col-11 col-sm-11 col-md-11 col-lg-11 col-xl-11  testCard d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" style="width:500px; height:500px">
        <p>hi am a card2</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think you did not got what I am trying to achieve, I am trying to resizing my div's

Comment: You can add style to divs to resize or reduce it

Comment: The Code Snippet Above!!